# resolution of iPad simulator

Tags: ios5, ios4, xcode4.2

I am new to iOS,  how to find what is the resolution of iPad. 
Googling resulted me to choose 748*1024, is this value represents in pixels? Or
do we have any alternate measurement unit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you know you can change the resolution of the iPad in the simulator?

Just choose from the "Device" submenu within the "Hardware" menu:

[image: different types of devices available in the simulator]

And the resolution that corresponds to these devices should correspond to the values you have already Googled up.

As for the unit of measurement, [even Apple's iPad specs (linked here for you)](http://www.apple.com/ipad/specs/) mention Pixels. Apple is trying to get developers away and off the idea of thinking in pixels (because we have to plan for screens of different sizes and resolutions), but Apple still uses that "pixel" measurement themselves.

Comment: you mean in the iPad simulator output, settings options? i don't see any option called  Hardware. Kindly bare,i m new. ;).

Comment: I've never seen an iPad / iPhone simulator without a "Hardware" menu? What menu options appear in your simulator? which SDK are you using?

Comment: In the simulator itself. Xcode and the Simulator are two different apps running on your Macintosh. You should absolutely have a "hardware" menu in the simulator. You will not have a "hardware" menu in Xcode.

Comment: Ha, i Found, there is option called iPad (retina), i have chosen this option, but still the images are adjusted. Is it expected behavior ?

Comment: I'm not sure.  This sounds like a completely separate question (which you could ask on StackOverflow).